# embarrassingly parallel in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Are there any functions in R for embarrassingly parallel as my codes are totally independently and don't require any communications between processes (without return values)?

Currently I am using sfLapply from snowfall package, but my codes always give me an error

```
 Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
```

It seems the error is caused by failed connections among sockets and might related with longer runtime in some processes. I want to try the embarrassingly parallel to minimize communications between sockets.

My session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C        
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C           
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] snowfall_1.84-6 snow_0.3-13    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: The [parallel](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) package is included with R.  Did you look at that?

Comment: @GSee Thanks for the tip. I am reading a paper about parallel package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the parallel package as the backend since it is fully cross-platform compatible. I also recommend the 'foreach' package since it is very easy to port code between systems with different numbers of cores.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I use parallel package which seems solve my problem until now.